How to sell Unicolor enlarger
What is the best way to find a new home for a Unicolor enlarger?
Also help with how to turn it on to verify that it works.

I’m voting to close this question because for me this question is not related to photography

Best bet is probably eBay.  And if you don't know anything about its condition then sell it "as is" but don't expect a lot of $$ for it.  Alternatively look for second hand camera shops in your area.

Here are some good choices:

Offer it to a local photography club.
Offer it to a local school/college/university that has photography courses.
Offer to donate it to a local charity thrift or second-hand store.
Bring it to a photography store that sells used equipment to see if they want to buy it.
See if any local photography or art stores have a physical bulletin board where they allow people to post listings for used equipment.
See if a pawn shop has interest in it.
List it for free/sale online; for example Craigslist, OfferUp, or eBay.

For help turning it on, we would need to know the specific model number.  If you donate it, you don't have to worry about turning it on.  It should include a power cord that includes a switch, and sometimes a voltage regulator, but you may be missing some of the parts required to turn it on.
